# CF query two different databases to match ID with Name

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have two databases on different servers and two tables that I need to combine to show the name of an ID. How do I query two different databases at the same time?

```
datasource="DB1, DB2" ?
```

So here I have a query how do I combine both databases and tables in order to match my `op_id` with the `assoc_name`?

```
    <cfquery name="processTable" datasource="DB1, DB2">
        SELECT *
        FROM [DB1].dbo.Dealer_Track_Work, [DB1].dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers, [DB2].dbo.tco_associates
        WHERE [DB1]dbo.Dealer_Track_Work.dealerID = [DB1].dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.id,
              [DB1].dbo.Dealer_Track_Work.op_id = [DB2].dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.assoc_name,
              [DB1].dbo.Dealer_Track_Work.Closed_by = [DB2]dbo.Dealer_Track_Dealers.assoc_name      
    </cfquery>
```

Comment: You should probably specify your DBMS for a question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<CFQUERY NAME="getDetailsQuery1" DATASOURCE="DB1"> 
 SELECT * FROM getDetailsA 
</CFQUERY>



<CFQUERY NAME="getDetailsQuery2" DATASOURCE="DB2"> 
 SELECT * FROM getDetailsB 
</CFQUERY> 


<CFQUERY NAME="getDetails" DBTYPE="query"> 
 SELECT * FROM getDetailsQuery1 
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM getDetailsQuery2 
 ORDER BY Name ASC 
</CFQUERY>
```

Here you have everything ...

```
<CFQUERY NAME="getDetailsWhere" DBTYPE="query"> 
 SELECT * FROM getDetails where id = '123'
</CFQUERY>
```

Function:

```
<cffunction name="qDisplay" output="yes" access="public" returntype="query">
<cfargument name="id"   type="string"   required="yes"  />

<CFQUERY NAME="getDetailsQuery1" DATASOURCE="DB1"> 
     SELECT * FROM getDetailsA 
    </CFQUERY>



<CFQUERY NAME="getDetailsQuery2" DATASOURCE="DB2"> 
 SELECT * FROM getDetailsB 
</CFQUERY> 


<CFQUERY NAME="getDetails" DBTYPE="query"> 
 SELECT * FROM getDetailsQuery1 
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM getDetailsQuery2 
 ORDER BY Name ASC 
</CFQUERY> 


<CFQUERY NAME="getDetailsWhere" DBTYPE="query"> 
 SELECT * FROM getDetails where id = #arguments.id#
</CFQUERY>

<cfreturn getDetailsWhere>
</cffunction>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: do step by step ... 1ST QUERY DUMP then  2nd query dump r u getting output?

Comment: Its still not working if you want to look into it further :)